# What is the LINQ equivalent to MIN?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

What is the C# LINQ equivalent to the SQL MIN function?

I would like to convert the following SQL to LINQ:

```
Select MIN(dbo.Orders.OrderTimestamp) as MinimumTimeStamp From dbo.Orders;
```

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
var MinimumTimeStamp = Orders.Select(order => order.OrderTimeStamp)
                             .Min();
```

Just noticed the Linq to SQL tag -

```
var MinimumTimeStamp = DataContext.Orders.Select(order => order.OrderTimeStamp)
                                         .Min();
```

Comment: FYI: this is mixing query expression syntax with fluent syntax into a result that simply won't compile. For query expression, it would be `= (from o in db.Orders select o.OrderTimeStamp).Min();` See Darin's answer for an appropriate fluent syntax version.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - shows just how much I lean on VS when not paying attention.

Answer (score 7):

There's a [Min function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#minSimple). So maybe something along the lines of:

```
var min = db.Orders.Min(x => x.OrderTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 3):

On a collection, you can use `.Min()` which is an extension method in the `System.Linq` namespace.

If IntelliSense isn't providing this to you then you need to add a `using System.Linq;` statement to your file.